# Can int property be not written to XML during serialization if it is zero?

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I have the following issue:

I have an integer property and would like it not to be written to XML during serialization if it is zero and only written if it has the value different from zero (one, two etc.) Is it possible to do somehow?

```
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int MyIntProperty;
```

Comment: See the following: [previous question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818513/xml-serialization-hide-null-values

Comment: @Maess click the "help" button next to "Add Comment" to see the proper format for an inline link