# Filter Serialized class properties to reduce WebAPI payload

Tags: c#, webforms, asp.net-web-api, json.net

a C# ASP.NET Webform site using WebAPI

I have a petapoco class that has 50 properties on it, but for certain WebAPI methods I would like to filter what properties are serialized and sent to the client in the HttpResponseMessage (to reduce the payload).

For Example let say I have the following class properties in a class:

```
ID, FirstName, LastName, Address, City, State, Zip, DOB
```

I need some WebApi methods to serialize every property, but maybe another method I only want to return

```
ID, FirstName, LastName
```

Is there a built in way to handle this?
If not, what's the best way to build out something to handle this?

**Edit**: I'm looking for a way to do this without modifying the class

Comment: If you are using Json, you can take a look at the following which describes about creating a custom contract resolver for this: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create ShouldSerialize methods for each property.

[Xml serialization - Hide null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818513/xml-serialization-hide-null-values)

Gives you the ability to dynamically decide which fields get serialized. Don't worry that the link says XML, should work for JSON serialization too.

Comment: ShouldSerialize would work, but I'm looking for a way to do this without modifying the serializable class or having to create a partial class.

Answer (score 0):

uses the [JsonIgnoreAttribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm) to exclude a property from serialization.

for example in model.cs:

```
public class Account
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string State { get; set; }
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: This is often not a viable approach for model code that is autogenerated.