# Deserialize XML with optional different name

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I have this class definition

```
public class Foo
{

}
```

Which deserializes into this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

</Foo>
```

This xml file layout already exists on client machines.

I want to rename the class from `Foo` to `Footastic`.

```
public class Footastic
{

}
```

Any new serialize of the now called class `Footastic`, should serialize as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Footastic xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

</Footastic>
```

My question is how can I tell the deserialization to accept **either** `Foo` or `Footastic`?

I know I could "rename" the `Footastic` to `Foo` by specifing the `XmlRoot` attribute.

```
[XmlRoot("Foo")]
public class Footastic
{

}
```

BUT this would also change any new serialization of the object, this is undesired.

A new serialization should serialize as `Footastic` ONLY old xml files containing the old name `Foo` should be supported while deserializing `Footastic`.

Just in case you need the code for deserializing/serializing. I am not really doing anything fancy.

Deserialize:

```
public static T? Deserialize<T>(string fileName)
{
    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        return default;

    using FileStream streamReader = new(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    using var xr = XmlReader.Create(streamReader);
    XmlSerializer xmlDeSerializer = new(typeof(T));
    return (T?)xmlDeSerializer.Deserialize(xr);
}
```

Serialize:

```
public static void Serialize<T>(T? value, string fileName)
{
    if (value is null)
        return;

    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName) ?? "");

    using FileStream fileStream = new(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write);
    using var streamWriter = XmlWriter.Create(fileStream, new()
    {
        Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
        Indent = true
    });

    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new(typeof(T));
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, value);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define multiple names for XmlElement field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24707399/how-to-define-multiple-names-for-xmlelement-field)

Comment: @GSerg - if I am not mistaken, this only works on members of a class and not the class itself, or?

Comment: For the XmlElement one, yes. The custom deserializer however you can use.

Comment: @GSerg - sorry, I don't see how - https://dotnetfiddle.net/YEBBdc the event `UnknownElement` doesn't trigger

Comment: @GSerg - just to be clear, I also tried the other "Unknown" events eg. `UnknowNode` none of them trigger

Comment: Looks like you're right, it doesn't trigger for the root.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach.
Create a custom XML reader that replaces the name `Foo` with `Footastic` on the fly.

```
public class FooReader : XmlTextReader
{
    // Add other constructor overloads as needed.
    public FooReader(string url) : base(url) { }

    public override string LocalName
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.LocalName == "Foo")
                return "Footastic";
            return base.LocalName;
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this.

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Footastic));

using var fooReader = new FooReader("test.xml");

var foo = (Footastic)ser.Deserialize(fooReader);
```

This will accept both `Foo` and `Footastic`.

However, be careful! This will replace all Foo elements!
If you have elements with the same name in xml in other places, then you need to make additional checks.