# xml serialization attributes

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlignore

Is there an xml serialization attribute tor a class member to serialize that member only if the member is not null? I need something like if the member is null, that member should behave like it had the attribute `XmlIgnore`?

Regards

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818513/xml-serialization-hide-null-values)?

Comment: I will test it and i will let you know