# #if region does not work

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I wanna use a `#if` statement to skip serializing `val` when `val2` is true and to serialize `val` when `val2` is false. But my code seems not to work:

```
#if val2
    [XmlIgnore]
#else   
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "val")]
#endif
public bool val
{
    { get; set; } = false;
}

[XmlElement(ElementName = "val2")]
public bool val2
{
    { get; set; } = true;
}
```

What do I have to do to get it working? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add one of the following to your code, and `val` won't be serialized, when `val2` is true:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeval()
{
    return val2 == false;
}
```

or

```
public bool ShouldSerializeval()
{
    return !val2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define the symbol you are testing with `#define`. These are pre-processor directives and you cannot use normal property names etc as those come into play during compilation which happens after pre-processing.

This is from the standard:

> Evaluation of a pre-processing expression always yields a boolean value. The rules of evaluation for a pre-processing expression are the same as those for a constant expression (§7.19), **except that the only user-defined entities that can be referenced are conditional compilation symbols.**

As pointed out in [this questio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5818571/1239433)n, you need something like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public bool val { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeval()
    {
       return !val2;
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "val2")]
    public bool val2 { get; set; }  
}

void Main()
{
    Item item = new Item(){val=true, val2=true};

    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Item));
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    xs.Serialize(sw, item);
    sw.ToString();
}
```

Comment: but how can I define a value, which shows me, if `val2` is true or false?

Comment: you can't use `val2` in a pre-processing directive at all. Are you trying to hide `val` if `val2` is true?