# Not serialized a property null or uninitialized

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I want to serialise a object with a `DateTime` property

If the property is not initialized so I have :

`<DateTime>0001-01-01T00:00:00</DateTime>`

But if I use a `DateTime?` type I have :

```
<DateTime d4p1:nil="true" xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
```

I want this property will not be serialized if it is null or uninitialized.

How to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using XmlSerializer, you should add a property called `ShouldSerializeYourProperty` and return `yourDateTime.HasValue`

[Xml serialization - Hide null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818513/xml-serialization-hide-null-values)