# Conditional XML Serialization in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xamarin.ios, xml-serialization

I have a class being serialized with the following property:

```
[XmlAttribute("Phone Number")]
public string PhoneNumber{ get; set; }

public bool ShouldSerializePhoneNumber()
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(PhoneNumber);
}
```

However, if the Phone Number is left empty, it's still serializing it. (phonenumber="").

PhoneNumber is set to string.Empty when my object is being created.
Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xml serialization - Hide null values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818513/xml-serialization-hide-null-values)

Comment: see the note about XmlAttribute in the linked question