# Serialise empty strings as nulls so they are not output

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I've got an XSD which has been supplied by a third party and I've then converted this into classes using `xsd.exe`.

Due to the fact we do not own this XSD, I'm trying to not alter the generated classes in any way.

Without manually applying a blank string check to every single field we are mapping, e.g.:

```
!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field) ? field : null;
```

I can't think of an easy way to serialise the blank strings in a way which means they are not output at all (no tag is produced).

The reason we cannot output blank strings is because the XSD has pattern constraints such as `StringM50m1` which I believe means a minimum length of 1 is required (however, they are happy to not receive the tag if there is no content) which fail post-output validation with the following message:

> The `'field'` element is invalid - The value `''` is invalid according to its datatype `'StringM50m1'` - The Pattern constraint failed.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818513/xml-serialization-hide-null-values

Comment: It's an interesting approach however it looks like I would have to generate a function for every single field? there are a lot of fields! thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use XmlSerializer you can add XmlDefaultValue for required properties:

```
private static void Serialize()
{
    XsdClass xc = new XsdClass();
    xc.SomeString1 = string.Empty;
    xc.SomeString2 = "value";
    xc.SomeString3 = null;

    XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
    XmlAttributes attribs = new XmlAttributes();
    attribs.XmlDefaultValue = string.Empty;
    foreach (var prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(XsdClass)).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().Where(x => !x.IsReadOnly && x.PropertyType == typeof(string)))
        overrides.Add(typeof(XsdClass), prop.Name, attribs);

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XsdClass), overrides);
    string result;
    using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, xc);
        result = textWriter.ToString();
    }
}

public class XsdClass 
{
    public string SomeString1 { get; set; }
    public string SomeString2 { get; set; }
    public string SomeString3 { get; set; }
}
```