# XML Serializer ignore attribute depends on condition

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am using `XmlConvert`. For the one instance of `Class`, only one property will have a value, another will be empty.

```
public class Class
{
    [XmlAttribute("ValueA")]
    public decimal? ValueA { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("ValueB")]
    public decimal? ValueB { get; set; }
}
```

The problem here is that the serializer can't serialize null property.
How can I show only one property with value?
Example:

```
var item = new Class { ValueA = 1, ValueB = null}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<model>
    <ValueA>1</ValueA>
</model>
```

Comment: I think you’re looking for the ShouldSerializeValueB pattern to determine whether it should be serialised.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xml serialization - Hide null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818513/xml-serialization-hide-null-values)

Comment: Cannot serialize member 'ValueB ' of type System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]. XmlAttribute/XmlText cannot be used to encode complex types.

Comment: Even if ValueB has a value it will not work, It's not allowed to have 'type?' with XmlAttribute, maybe it's allowed with XMLElement

Comment: `<ValueA>1</ValueA>` is element, not attribute. So use `[XmlElement("ValueA")]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to wrap your nullable properties to get it work. For example, for your `ValueA`

```
public class Class
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public decimal? ValueA { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("ValueA")]
    public decimal ValueAUnwrapped
    {
        //this will only called, when ShouldSerializeValueAUnwrapped return trues, so no NRE here
        get => ValueA.Value; 
        set => ValueA = value;
    }
    
    public bool ShouldSerializeValueAUnwrapped() => ValueA.HasValue;
}
```

This code instructs serializer to serialize `ValueAUnwrapped` property only when the original `ValueA` property has value. This is achieved by adding `ShouldSerialize<Name>()` function which serializer will call for corresponding `Name` property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/defining-default-values-with-the-shouldserialize-and-reset-methods?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

You will also need to pereform the same trick for the `ValueB`.